# Phonegap build 3.7, HTML, window.open redirect on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, redirect

I am trying to do a simple redirect in a Phonegap built (version 3.7) from the opening index.html to another html (main2b.html) on an iphone with no success. It works fine on Android.  This is a simplified test of what I need to do.

If I window.location.href='http://www.google.com' as an example it DOES NOT work. (and yes I have white listed it in my config.xml)
If I window.location.href='main2b.html' it just spins and does NOT work either.

For testing purposes the main2b.html is just a simple 'hello' in a div. 
I have tried various pathing options of main2b.html with no success so I feel it is not a pathing issue. Both html files are in the same location.

Here is the code sample.  Would appreciate any thoughts. This seems like such a simple thing and cannot figure out what is wrong.

Once this simple test works, I need to do something like this where I will detect if my app is 'offline' and as such go to a different html file.  This is why I am doing this before any jquery/mobile init stuff which would come later if I detect I am 'online'.

The index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
     <head>             
        <title>The Conspiracy Show</title> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no, " />

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

        <!-- Phonegap build stuff required ----------- -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>      
        <!------------------------>
      
        <script>              
            function onLoad(){
                alert('here at onLoad');
                document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
              }
            
            function deviceReady() {
                alert('here at deviceReady')
                window.location.href = "main2b.html";
            }             
        </script>  
       
    </head> 
    <body  onload="onLoad()"> 
        
    </body>
</html>
```

main2b.html looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
        
    <head> 
      <title>The Conspiracy Show App</title>  
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="conspiracy Richard Syrett talk show Coasttocoastam paranormal callIn"/> 

        <!-- Required Stuff for PhoneGap prevent page flickering in iOS----------- -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

        <!-- Phonegap build stuff required ----------- -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>      
     
    </head>

    <body style="background:#2D5873;" >
        <div align="center" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
            Hello
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own problem.  Apparently, in iPhone, if you dont specifically close the splash screen (which can only be done after deviceReady), any redirection will not work.  On android, the splash screen close can be done immediately.  Anyway, problem solved.